# filter response data date wise vue

Tags: date, filter, vue.js

How can we filter response data, date wise in vue2? (this month data, this year data, this week data) when I click 'month' button I wish to get this month data only.

I got the response like this - [ { "date": "2017-02-05", "views": 1, "readMore": 1 }, { "date": "2018-03-15", "views": 1, "readMore": 1 }, { "date": "2018-01-27", "views": 2, "readMore": 2 } ].

thanks in advance

```
computed: {
  DateWise: function () {
    if(this.duration === 'year'){ 
      return this.data.filter(item => item.date.includes(new Date().getFullYear()));
    }
    else if(this.duration === 'month'){ 
      return this.data.filter(item => item.date.includes(new Date().getMonth()+1));
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON doesn't understand dates, so a good practice is to convert date strings to date objects when you deserialize. Then, you want to put your source data in a store, and create computed properties for your filtered arrays.

[Here is a working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/c3vnnLLm/21/)

Here's the code for the filtered property...

```
displayDates(){
    var now = new Date(Date.now());
    switch(vueStore.currView){
    case 'all': return vueStore.allDates;
    case 'month' : return vueStore.allDates.filter(
        line => line.date > new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(),0)
    );
    case 'year' : return vueStore.allDates.filter(
        line => line.date > new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0,0)
    )
  }
}
```