# Filter data by minutes VueJs

Tags: javascript, datetime, vue.js, time, filter

I have a data table in my VueJs page and getting its data via ajax request. The return data is like this

```
{
    name: "Test Name",
    created_at: "2019-06-14 07:31:15"
}
```

I have buttons which should filter the data with the following rules:

```
Created data within the last 5 mins
Created data within the last 15 mins
Created data within the last 30 mins
```

Given my `created_at` how do I do this? I have this current function

```
computed: {
    filterData() {
        return this.customers.filter(item => item.created_at.includes(new Date().getDay()+1));
    }
}
```

The data `this.customers` is my data from the ajax request.

I just reference it from here [filter response data date wise vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665979/filter-response-data-date-wise-vue) . Based on this I expect the data to be filtered  by data which is 1 day old. But this also does not work to me. Maybe because my date is datetime instead of date?

Comment: I think what you need is a library to do this for you, please try this for some such features: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/

Comment: I agree with @kaushik94, use moment library.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys but I don't prefer to use moment or loading another library to compute the minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your date format is parseable by default JS Date function, you can try the below code. Minus (-) between two dates will give diff in milliseconds. Divide by 60 * 1000 gives diff in mins.

```js
a = [{
    name: "Test Name",
    created_at: "2019-09-29 10:00:15"
},
{
    name: "Test Name",
    created_at: "2019-09-29 10:21:15"
},
{
    name: "Test Name",
    created_at: "2019-09-29 09:21:15"
},
{
    name: "Test Name",
    created_at: "2019-09-29 09:50:15"
}]

const filterByLastMins = (mins, arr) => {
    const currentTime = new Date();
    return arr.filter((elem) => {
        const diffInMins = (currentTime -  Date.parse(elem.created_at)) / (1000 * 60);
        return diffInMins < mins
    })
}

res = filterByLastMins(60, a);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks works perfect for me. I don't want to use another library just to compute minutes.